# Program stuck on AcceptTcpClient

Tags: c#

I am using  a  modality emulator when i am connecting  program with emulator,
program hang on Accept Tcp Client..Why?

public virtual void Run()

```
{
  if (this.ss == null)

    return;

  TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient) null;

  while (!this.m_Stop)

  {

    try

    {

      tcpClient = this.ss.AcceptTcpClient();

      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.handler.Handle), (object) tcpClient);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

    }

   }

}
```

Here ss is the TcpListener

Comment: Did you read the manual? `AcceptTcpClient is a blocking method that returns a TcpClient that you can use to send and receive data. Use the Pending method to determine if connection requests are available in the incoming connection queue if you want to avoid blocking.`

Answer (score 2):

`AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking method that you use when you are creating a TCP Server.

'Blocking' means that it will wait until a TCP client connects to it before returning.

Did you mean to create a TCP Client instead? If so, just use `TCPClient.Connect()`, passing the server IP and port that you are connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

[AcceptTcpClient()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will block until a connection is received. The program will continue once a client connects to your TcpListener.